# Angular.js extend $inject so it can load files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm starting a new `angular` project from a scratch and I want to avoid using `require.js`, `browserify` or `webpack` entirely. I'm gonna put all my code into separate files - no monolithic **controllers.js** or **directives.js** files...

Few options that are left are:

1. Use `<script>` tags and always put new files at the bottom (downside I might mess up order of the files at some point)
2. Use **concatination** mechanism, i.e. `gulp-concat` or `grunt-concat`

Both of them are ugly - first is maintenance nightmare and the second requires build step and file watcher setup...

The closest thing that I could use is `require.js` but I'm really disgusted with how the code looks after combining angular with require:

```
define([], function () {
  angular.module('app').controller('BlaBlaController', function () { ... });
})
```

Since angular is handling all the DI for me require.js is used only for file loading which is kinda sad and makes require.js overkill for such a small task.

What I want to make is extend `$inject` service so that it would know how to load external files and that's how imagine it should look like:

- Create `di.config.js` file where I specify paths for various "injectables" (much like require.conf.js
- Create a simple script loader that would know how to recursively load modules
- Now for DI mechanism

--

```
if (injectableIsLoaded) {
  angular.module('app').controller('Controller', function (dep1) {});
} else if (injectableHasPath) {
  diLoader.load(injectablePath).then(evalModule);
} else {
  throw "No path for module";
}
```

Does anyone know if that would be possible at all?

What I win from this - I don't need to wrap my angular code in weird require.js calls, don't need a build step, can keep all files separete and load them separatly on demand...

Comment: This would completely change the logic of injection - injection is currently synchronous, having to download files would make it asynchronous, which would require significant changes to angular.

Comment: **Both of them are ugly - first is maintenance nightmare**, and what you want to achieve is ugly as well.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the problem is, if you use comments above the `<script>` tags then you can easily keep track of what you are doing. What backend are you using? with MVC I've created a really nice bundle builder to keep track of everything for me

Comment: @Naeem-Shaikh FYI I wasn't asking for advice about style

Comment: @VytautasButkus it isn't styling advice.... its code advice!

Comment: @No1_Melman I'm not using backend at all (I don't need it) everything is served staticaly (locally with grunt/gulp and remotly s3 or anything similar). P.S. the problem is that you either have to use bundler or build step for everything to work where I want something similary to what require.js provides but without additional crappy looking code wraps..

Comment: @Sacho is DI so tightly coupled to angular core that I couldn't make it work around?

Comment: So your front end application isn't going to interact with anything?

Comment: @No1_Melman it is but for that I don't need backend, I'm using cors.. And I really doubt it has anything to do about the question itself :)

Comment: Loading the JS files at runtime dynamically just will not work well without something like require.us and will cause the page to load very slowly. The best thing to do would be to use so ething like grunt-concant. For any project of decent size concant should just be one of the many things you would do.

Comment: @Enzey and at Everyone else I'm not asking for a advice about performance, about style or anything else the question is simple "Is it possible to extend angular DI so that it could load files?" Please stop off-topic and don't create more questions if you do not have anything to say about the question that I asked. Thank you

Comment: @VytautasButkus You could certainly extend the DI to do whatever you want. But if you want *angular* to use your DI extension, then you'd need to modify it. Angular depends on DI being synchronous.

Comment: @Sacho I know that it's possible to work around "angular depending on DI being synchronous" because we used require.js together with angular before. I was wondering maybe someone already did something like that or knows what is the best way to do that because I couldn't find anything on net so far

Comment: What you said doesn't make sense. Using require.js and angular's DI are orthogonal - and angular still requires its DI to be synchronous.

Comment: 1. There is a way to lazy load angular modules using require.js 2. I believe it should be possible to override angular injection mechanism, so it loads modules before running original dependency injection mechanism on top of that